# Can i get an example of how an sql injection can occur?

Tags: php, sql, security, code-injection

I am new to PHP and coming close to launching.  I am using mysql_real_escape_string(); for all user input and all $_GET and $_REQUEST variables. I wanted to test it out but not sure how it's done so i can prevent it and put in proper measures.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508431/how-to-mysql-injection-this

Answer (score 4):

Try inputting a string similar to the one below in all your form fields (including the hidden ones):

```
blah'"blah
```

If you're not escaping it properly, you'll get a sql error. If you get that sql error, you should then be able to figure out how to write a query that does something different than what the original one intended.

Comment: ok i didn't get an sql error but i useed in a form that displays data and it showed me blah'"blah

Answer (score 3):

> I am using mysql_real_escape_string(); for all user input and all $_GET and $_REQUEST variables

well, you are entirely wrong.

First, mysql_real_escape_string() has nothing to do with "user input". This is database-related function, not user-related.
Next, it has nothing to do with "all input" as it's usage limited to strings only. So, if you have a code like this

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id";
```

you have here escaping absolutely useless and protects nothing.

as for the test - it's kinda tricky. however, there are tools in the internet, I am sure you can google some.

Comment: You should post a PoC for this:  `http://localhost/vuln.php?id=sleep(30)`