# SQL Injection - select * from table where column in (

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

I have a statement similar to this, where 'name' can be inserted

```
select * from table where column in (/**name*/ 'name')
```

I am currently checking for `')'`.

ex. they can put in `'*/; drop table--'`, but sql will throw error because no parentheses right?

If they cannot close the parentheses, is there still a security risk?

Comment: What database are you using (e.g. MySql, Oracle, MS Sql Server)?

Comment: *Use placeholders for all data* - this prevents all injection locations where data can be bound. For other places where dynamic non-data is used (e.g. column names) consider deconstruction/reconstruction and whitelisting.

Comment: There is little reason to check for these specifics of security. You should have one function that cleans the user input entirely and simply call it repeatedly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508431/how-to-demonstrate-sql-injection-in-this-php-and-mysql-code?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: It's a framework that's been here, (bad coding on their part) but we want to patch it up temporarily. really, i just want to redo the framework. Still, is there some way that a malicious user could bypass closing the parenthese?

Comment: Surely it is apostrophes and the `*/` sequence that you should be worried about, not parentheses. Those are the immediate delimiters on the two instances of `name`.

Comment: Don't waste your time writing and testing new code trying to sanitize data.  Use placeholders in parametrized queries where the work is all done for you.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html gives you some examples.

Answer (score 3):

Why risk it?  Always use SQL query parameters for dynamic values, then you don't need to worry about escaping or whether you're at risk.

If you specify what programming language and RDBMS brand you're using, I'll point you to a resource with examples of using query parameters.

Comment: It's a framework that's been here, (bad coding on their part) but we want to patch it up temporarily. really, i just want to redo the framework. Still, is there some way that a malicious user could bypass closing the parenthese?

Comment: Yes, they could inject a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - what if they terminate the statement (albeit invalid), and then execute their own?

This works (tested it locally on mysql):

```
select * from TABLE where (col = ''; select * from TABLE;
```

The first statement generates an error, but the second statement runs fine.

Comment: Most APIs do not support multi-query by default.

Comment: I just ran that from command line mysql (5.x enterprise-commercial-advanced). It looks like at least mysql likes to support it by default (not sure if languages override it, though): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html

Comment: I take it back.  PDO seems to support multi-query by default in both `PDO::exec()` and `PDO::query()`.  At least in Mysqli, you have to deliberately shoot yourself in the foot by calling `mysqli::multi_query()`.

Comment: I'd say the mysql client is not a programming interface, it's meant to run multiple queries separated by semicolons, either interactively or from an SQL script, but not from a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If I take your post literally, you want to insert name in two places, once in the comment and once in the text string:

```
select * from table where column in (/**/select column from table where column !=/**/ '/select column from table where column !=/*');
```

Answer (score -1):

Always escape any user-inputted data.

```
mysqli_real_escape_string
```

Or old school

```
mysql_real_escape_string
```

Comment: Agreed: -1 for poor practice

Comment: It's better than *not* escaping strings, but yes, please use query parameters.  They're easier and safer than escaping strings.